# How to draw a graph in LaTeX

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw something like

[image: Bipartite graph in a rectangular fashion]

in LaTeX.

I'm new to LaTeX and have no idea how to draw it. How do I do?

Comment: Well, I don't know about the rest, but I know it'll start with `\documentclass`.  Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. :)

Comment: For future reference, especially with respect to how to include an MWE, compare [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/232076/8528), which was asked at almost the same time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One possibility using [`TikZ`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/pgf); some circular nodes are placed and named using `\foreach` loops and then the arrows are drawn using the `(<name>.<angle>)` syntax:

[image]

The code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=1mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{
  mycircle/.style={
  circle,
  draw,
  inner sep=5pt
  }
}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\foreach \Valor/\Texto in {1/$7$,2/$11$,3/$18$,4/$12$}
  \node[mycircle,label={left:\Texto}] at (0,-\Valor cm) (column\Valor) {};
\foreach \Valor/\Texto in {1/$-10$,2/$-23$,3/$-15$}
  \node[mycircle,label={above:\Texto}] at (\Valor cm,1cm) (row\Valor) {};
\node[above right=5pt and 20pt of row3] {Demands};
\node[below=5pt and 20pt of column4] {Supplies};

\draw[->]
  (column1.20) -| (row1.-110) node[midway,above left] {$5$};  
\draw[->]
  (column1.-20) -| (row2.-140) node[midway,above left] {$6$};  
\draw[->]
  (column2.20) -| (row1.-70) node[midway,above left] {$8$};  
\draw[->]
  (column2.0) -| (row2.-110) node[midway,above left] {$4$};  
\draw[->]
  (column2.-20) -| (row3.-110) node[midway,above left] {$3$};  
\draw[->]
  (column3) -| (row2.-70) node[midway,above left] {$9$};  
\draw[->]
  (column4.20) -| (row2.-40) node[midway,above left] {$3$};  
\draw[->]
  (column4.-20) -| (row3.-70) node[midway,above left] {6};  

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```